# Java Pattern for generating and parsing data in stream

Tags: java, parsing, design-patterns, serialization

I have certain protocol that I need to parse or generate. The parsing takes an `InputStream` and produce different type of objects depending the byte stream. The generator takes different inputs and spit out an `OutputStream` that allows writing to a target stream. Before reading / writing to the stream there might be some header variables that needs to be initialized.

For code right now looks something like follows:

```
// Parser.
DataX parsed = DataX.parse(new ByteInputStream(new byte [] {..}));
// Access short field of DataX.
System.out.println(parsed.getX() + parsed.getY()); // data in the header.
// Access some long field by spitting InputStream.
System.out.println(parsed.buildInputStream().readFully()); // data as bytes.

// Generator.
OutputStream outstream = 
   DataX.Generator(new FileOutputStream('output')).setX(x).setY(y).build();
// Write data.
outstream.write(new byte[] {...});
```

`DataX` extends a class `Data` that implements two methods `deserialize` and `serialize` as abstract method which will eventually be called somewhere inside `parse()` and `Generator()`.

This is a self-made design pattern, so I would like to ask if this makes sense and whether there is a more Java-ist way to do this kind of thing ?

---

Edit: The reason the stream needs to be incorporate is because the data might be huge (such as a file) and will not be feasible/desirable to store it entirely in the memory.

Comment: What is `data`?  That is not declared in your code.

Comment: @saka1029 It's just a mock code do not expect it to run, data is a byte array / byte of course, since it's an `OutputStream`, but I edit to make it clear...

Comment: What is the difference between `outstream.write(new byte[] {...});` in your code and `new FileOutputStream("output").write(new byte[] {...});`.

Comment: The stream was written with the header before it is returned to the user, and it may be override internally to transform the data.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is a good idea to keep data (header values) and its presentation (streams) separate.

Some component accepts streams ([Factory method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern)
and returns plain objects.

Those objects are serialized to streams via a different component later on.

It shouldn't matter if it is a stream at the moment. If later you want to work with Json objects - the design doesn't need to change dramatically.

Comment: Sorry I do not get your point. Are you suggesting not to use stream?

Comment: Not at all, I am saying the data model and de/serialization should not be dependent on each other. Now you are using streams, tomorrow you want JSON text and the new de/serialization will integrate just fine if the data model is not tied to streams.

Comment: Could you give an example on how separation will look like ?

Answer (score 0):

I think a synmetrical pattern is easy to understand.

```
// Parser
DataX header = new DataX();   // uninitialized header
InputStream is = header.input(new FileInputStream(...));
// At this point header is initialized.
// user reads data from is.

// Generator
DataX header = new DataX();   // uninitialized header
header.setX(x).setY(y);       // initialize header
OutputStream os = header.output(new FileOutputStream(...));
// At this point header is written to os.
// user writes data to os.
```